# LuaHBTex not working with scrartcl on Fedora

Tags: koma-script, texlive, linuxfedora, luahbtex

I am running Fedora on my laptop and my desktop, presumably same versions on both systems TexLive 2020 installed via dnf.

If I try to run this simple document using "lualatex file.tex" on the console:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6277 ...Senglish,usenglish}\contentsname{Contents}
                                                  %
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6277 ...Senglish,usenglish}\contentsname{Contents}
                                                  %
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6347 ...usenglish}\listfigurename{List of Figures}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6347 ...usenglish}\listfigurename{List of Figures}
                                                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6352 ...h,usenglish}\listtablename{List of Tables}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6352 ...h,usenglish}\listtablename{List of Tables}
                                                  
? 
) (./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
[1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux))
 397 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:21,3:2,4:1,5:24,6:1,7:27,9:10,11:3
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 3360 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I already tried reinstalling texlive-koma-scripts. PDFlatex runs this code fine though. I am quite lost on where to start debugging this.

As aked by Ulrike:
Full log file contents:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=lualatex 2021.1.4)  3 MAY 2021 21:45
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/Jorn/.texlive2020/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic-dev/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-05-06.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2020-
05-06.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e353f7ced917p+1
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/Jorn/.texlive2020/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic-dev/names".
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-define 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / databa
se
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-plug 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Inserting `Harf pre_output_filter callback' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'
.
Inserting `Harf wrapup_run callback' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `Harf finish_pdffile callback' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `Harf glyph_info callback' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-suppress 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / suppress
Lua module: luaotfload-szss 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box27
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 135.
Package scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `11pt'.
(scrartcl)             This is correct!
(scrartcl)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=11pt'.
(scrartcl)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl)             you'd have to use `fontsize=11pt' there
(scrartcl)             instead of `11pt', too.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input li
ne 2212.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)

luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/Jorn/.texlive2020/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count80
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea)             instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1738.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip47
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4761.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4761.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip48
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl)           for `\part on input line 4769.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip49
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4779.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4779.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4789.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4789.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip51
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4799.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4799.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4809.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4809.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip53
\belowcaptionskip=\skip54
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box28
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6040.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip55
\c@figure=\count87
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6052.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip56
\c@table=\count88
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6216.

! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6277 ...Senglish,usenglish}\contentsname{Contents}
                                                  %
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6277 ...Senglish,usenglish}\contentsname{Contents}
                                                  %
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6347 ...usenglish}\listfigurename{List of Figures}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6347 ...usenglish}\listfigurename{List of Figures}
                                                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.6352 ...h,usenglish}\listtablename{List of Tables}
                                                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.6352 ...h,usenglish}\listtablename{List of Tables}
                                                  
? 
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.

 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
! Argument of \strip@prefix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
Runaway argument?
undefined
! Paragraph ended before \strip@prefix was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.3 \begin{document}
                  
? 
[1

{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 2782 strings out of 492902
 100000,319454 words of node,token memory allocated
 397 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:21,3:2,4:1,5:24,6:1,7:27,9:10,11:3
 8451 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 45i,6n,56p,10098b,248s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 3360 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: show the complete log-file (but it could be difficult to debug, the files in end texlive 2019 are older, and the one in end texlive 2020 newer than yours).

Comment: I updated with full log. Would you recomend to keep texlive up to date via tlmgr? what i've read online, most people recomend to keep texlive packages up to date via dnf/package manager and not tlmgr...

Comment: most of the regulars here have a vanilla texlive 2021 and update it with tlmgr. But beside this: I don't see how to debug this, I can't reproduce it with a current texlive.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick reply! I will give this a try then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike suggested the problem went away by installing a vanilla texlive on the side and switching to it.